# How to get the property value of dynamically generated usercontrol's control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

This is the code of my user control.

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewUserControl.ascx.cs"           

  Inherits="usercontrol.NewUserControl" %>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton1</asp:LinkButton>
```

and on another form on the button click event i am loaoding the user control.like this-

```
    protected void LoadControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newuc = LoadControl("NewUserControl.ascx") as NewUserControl;          
        form1.Controls.Add(newuc);
        Session["chksession"] = ((int)Session["chksession"]) + 1;

        if (((int)Session["chksession"]) >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < ((int)Session["chksession"]); i++)
            {
                newuc = LoadControl("NewUserControl.ascx") as NewUserControl;
                form1.Controls.Add(newuc);
            }
        }
    }
```

now user control can be loaded any no of times, now i need the text of all the textboxes present on the form on the click of a Button that is present on the .aspx page.
i am new to asp...need guidance.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to get the text of every textbox once you click on a button..? what are you planning to do with that text how or where are you going to store the text boxes..? why not write code for the OnClick Event for that button.. you need to be more specific on what you are wanting.. if you want to look thru the page of controls to see if they are Textboxes then look at using the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a property to your UserControl that allows you to get/set the text in `TextBox1`:

```
public string Text {
    get { return TextBox1.Text; }
    set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Access it like this in your button handler:

```
newuc.Text = "Setting the text";
string myString = newuc.Text; //getting the text
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you're loading the UserControls dynamically, you'll have to persist their values in a StateBag (ViewState, Session, etc.).

```
public string Text {
    get {
        //Default to any existing text
        string s = TextBox1.Text;
        //Use TextBox1.UniqueID to ensure a unique string for the ViewState key
        if (TextBox1.Text.Length == 0 & ViewState(TextBox1.UniqueID) != null) {
            //TextBox1.Text is empty, restore from ViewState
            s = ViewState(TextBox1.UniqueID).ToString;
        }
        return s;
    }
    set {
        //Set TextBox1.Text
        TextBox1.Text = value;
        //Store in ViewState as well
        ViewState(TextBox1.UniqueID) = TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: can someone tell me how to maintain the state of textboxes, i mean the value of textboxes disappear on every postback? is there any way to get out of this problem ?

Comment: @ramesh: What version of .Net are you using?